# BGE (Blender game engine) doesn't run on my pc

Tags: game-engine, error, installation

I downloaded BGE from https://upbge.org/#/download here.
A .rar file gets downloaded and I extract that file on the desktop but when I try to open the application inside it, it shows the error that BGE can't run on this PC.

I don't know why this is happening, I have windows 10. (I am downloading UPBGE 0.3)

This is the error
[image: error]

[image: All files]

Comment: There's certainly something corrupted, since all the files have 0kb... Try downloading again, extracting with another app, etc...

Comment: @JoelGomes Yeah I thought the same. I tried downloading again a couple of times but this error came up in all. Is there any tutorial on how to download UPBGE?